# How to redirect the output of a utility that generates lots of separate output files?

Tags: build, makefile, build-process, build-automation

My build process uses lots of closed-source 3rd-party utilities. These tools generate lots of files, separated into three categories: the files I want, reports, and crap. Sometimes I can choose the output directory of one or two of these files, but not all. The rest of the files just appear in the current directory or a brand-new subdirectory. Most of these unwanted files are not documented. New unwanted files appear in every new version of these utilities.

Is there a way to run these utilities and redirect all file system operations to some specified subdirectory, where I could copy out the good files before deleting the rest? I can change into a subdirectory to run the tools, but this messes things up since the build process is relative to the root of the project. (The tools have trouble finding the right files.)

UPDATE:

I was hoping for answers that used some sort of copy-on-write approach to the filesystem so that the tools run in the top-level but all files are generated into effectively their own subdirectory. If this is not an option, then I think the next best thing would be to change into a subdirectory to run the tool. The new question then becomes how to fix up the inputs to the tools such that tools can find the correct source files? This is non-trivial. Examples of inputs to fix are command-line arguments and filepaths inside of configuration files. This seems like an error-prone and possibly intractable problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a few of the ephemera that a build generates, in this example I'm mostly thinking ab

### Example: dependency files

  An example of this would be the **-MD** or **-MDD** flag for gcc, which generate dependency files that aid make in understanding whats changed since the last time you built. To the developer editing code, yeah, those could easily be considered junk - however they're critically important if you don't want to have to rebuild _everything_ every time you run 'make'.

  In this case, you could use a different target directory for your object files, which would put your dependency files in the same dir.

### Example: compiled object files

  Now, that example may or may not pertain to you, but there are many similar types of artifact generation that tools require to work 'correctly'., if you want to take it to an extreme, '.o' files could similarly be viewed as 'crap' by a developer who's trying to find a source file in a directory that has '.o' and '.c/.cpp' files intermixed.

  In this case, you can use a different object directory which is a fairly standard pattern, when running GCC you do something like

  gcc -c file.c -o ../objs/file.o

### Example: No really, **crap is crap**

  But, lets take the case where **crap** _really_ means **crap**. After the build you never ever want to see a 'type' of file thats generated during the build, it's random data or something and *must* be regenerated each build.

  In that case, just add a step at the end of your build that removes them once your product has successfully built. Simple as that. This is also a standard pattern in nightly builds where the intermediate files (objects, dependencies, etc..) don't matter as long as the build executes correctly and your product artifact passes whatever bare minimum expectations which usually are, no non-zero results from subtasks, all targets built correctly and packaging succeeded.

  In the case where the build fails, the next step of cleaning the ephemera is NOT run and you can go in and perform a post mortem on the build to understand why and fix it.

  If none of these suggestions resonate with you I urge you to get into more detail about the tools you're using and what you consider 'the crap', every build tool or language has it's own flavor and strategy (i.e. ant, maven, make, cmake, gcc, flex, java, perl, python, scones, quake, etc etc etc..) so without additional info it may be difficult to really come up with a good explanation of how to best resolve your issue.

UPDATED:

**Additional possible solutions**

### unionfs

  If you're using Linux to run your builds, a tool agnostic way to accomplish what you want would be to use [unionfs][1], where you can 'stack' directories on top of each other. It's fairly clever in that say you have the following directories:

  /home/login/src/
  /build/login/output_YY_MM_DD

  You could do a unionfs mount of /build/yourlogin/some_project_YY_MM_DD transparently on top of /home/login/src/, when you run a build however, all generated files would actually end up in /build/login/output_YY_MM_DD - this would actually accomplish what you want. But, again, only if you run Linux with unionfs. (This sadly doesn't work over NFS, never tried SMB but suspect the same..)

  To accomplish this you'd have to run a kernel with unionfs enabled (I believe there's a patch bundle you have to install), then do something like:

  ```
  mount -t unionfs -o dirs=/build/login/output_YY_MM_DD/=rw:/home/login/src/=ro
  ```

### Retargeting output

  Most build tools support the ability to target their output as long as you make sure that everything in the chain understands this. It's usually along the lines of '-o output_filename', although in your case for some tools (such as Xilinx's reportgen) '-o' really means the output directory.

  Bearing that in mind, if you really only have three basic types of outputs that you're dealing with, you just need to figure out which tools generate them and how to modify where they output.

  The only caveat with that approach is that if you retarget some build ephemera that is required in a follow up stage of building, obviously it won't be there - hence everything in the chain needing to know about the retargeting. That indeed can be tricky.

### Environment variable magic

  Often times if you dig around you can find environment variables that will trigger behaviors that may or may not be immediately available through config files or command line options. For instance, Xilinx's **Compxlib** honors **USE_OUTPUT_DIR_ENV**, which does pretty much what the name implies (You specify the environment variable that points to the directory you want to retarget to.

  The benefit of using an environment variable is that instead of having to root around and rewrite all the compilation rules to retarget some other directory by appending '-o blah', every tool that honors the environment variable will pick it up automatically.

  This technique is also useful if you have multiple architectures that you're building something for but you want use the source from a single source tree.

  #### tip: Relative directories and build config variables

  If you can stick relative directories in here and use variables you can monkey with things a little more dynamically

  ```
  NIGHTLY_BUILD_DIR=.build/${ARCH}
  USE_OUTPUT_DIR_ENV=NIGHTLY_BUILD_DIR
  ```

### Xilinx specific

  You should look at the IDE tools to see what might provide some high level ways of doing what you want - possibly by modifying your **Design Goals** in **Edit > Preferences > ISE General > Design Goals & Strategies**? I don't know for sure though.

  PlanAhead almost undoubtedly will have some settings for changing work directories or ignoring ephemera to separate builds for different targets. This is a fairly common pattern.

### Ignoring files

  It might require a bit of doing, but you could possibly just 'hide' the crap you don't want to see. Windows and OSX (and I'm assuming Linux) all support mechanisms when using GUI file browsing tools that can hide files based on file extension. Or, if you're using programs like 'ls' or 'grep' you can just filter out the stuff you don't want to see. Just as source control programs can be configured to ignore ephemera.

  A couple examples of this:

  - ls --ignore=*.d
  - rsync --exclude=.svn,*.d
  - grep --exclude=*.d

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The tools are Xilinx command-line utilities for generating the bitfiles that get downloaded to FPGAs. Some of the files really are crap. I think a lot of the complication comes from the fact that an FPGA "flow" has many paths from the beginning to the end, and often time a human is needed to determine the right path. It is not something easily automated.

Comment: Ahh, so in this context I think what 'crap' means is probably really something like 'object file', i.e. if you have an FPGA module that doesn't change from one build to the next - do you have to rebuild it if you change a separate module? If not, then crap doesn't really mean crap in that case.. However, there is a chance that you could modify your build to do what you want - two questions need to be answered, what generates bit file and what decides which bit files should be built? (I have a Xilinx 13.1 install here so I might be able to dummy something up..)

Comment: Take a look at the Xilinx command-line tools: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/devref.pdf. That is an older link but the interface should not have changed much. There are about 20 different utilities used to generate various object files. The output of the tools include the object files, plus reports, plus crap. If you are very careful, you can avoid having to regenerate object files sometimes. But often tools like ISE just regenerate everything. Tools like PlanAhead are a bit more sophisticated. ISE and PlanAhead both wrap the command-line tools.

Comment: These are all good suggestions. Unfortunately none of them work for my particular problem. unionfs is cool but very specific to the operating system and has lots of limitations, like you point out. Retargeting output and environmental magic only work if the tool supports it. Ignoring files does not solve the problem of tools overwriting each others files, in case you need to run multiple tools between cleaning up the crap. I think the best solution to my problem is actually Xilinx's PlanAhead or ISE GUIs, because that is what they are made for.

Comment: The trick with using PlanAhead or ISE is knowing which files to keep and which not to keep in version control. Also, keep all source outside of the project directory to minimize the version control problem. I've heard of someone using PlanAhead to setup the project, but then running the command-line tools using the PlanAhead project file as the input, in order to find all of the dependencies. This seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper script for each utility that `cd` to the appropriate directory and run the actual utility from there. Save these wrapper script in your "local" bin directory and put this directory first in your $PATH.

This will fail if the tool uses the full path when executing the 3rd party utilities.

You can [override the PATH variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding) that is specified in the Makefile from the command line like this:

```
$ make PATH=foo:$PATH
```

Comment: Yes, but how to I fixup my paths in my Makefiles and my temporary scripts for each of these utilities when I am no longer executing from the top-level directory? Managing these paths seems like a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. If these tools must run in the project root directory, then that's where they must run, and if they foul the nest then that's what they do.

Longer answer: maybe. If they really have to run in the project root directory, then so be it, but there may be a way to clean up their effluvia automatically. You don't know the names of the unwanted files and directories beforehand, but if you know the names of the *wanted* files and directories, you can whitelist them and delete everything else.

Alternatively, depending on the specifics of your project and OS, you could create a temporary directory with symbolic links to the files in the project root directory; to a third-party tool it would look just like the real root directory, but when the work was done you could pick out the good files and delete the rest, just as with an ordinary temp. This will work nicely as long as the tool doesn't try to create files in preexisting subdirectories -- in other words it will probably work, but no promises.

Comment: Good idea! It needs to run on both Windows and UNIX, so I'm not sure symbolic links are an option.

Comment: If you can, consider using http://www.cygwin.com/, it simulates posix compliant symlinks under Windows. Added bonus, if your modifications are shell scripts you just have to have a set of configuration files with paths stored in them and it'll work on both platforms.